# Call function in Typescript which is in HTML script tag

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript

I have function in my ASPX like this,

```
<script>         
    static function TestFunc(arg)
    {        
    alert("Yess");                  
    }     
</script>
```

How can I call this function in my typescript

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `static` means here; it's not valid JavaScript.  Is it some ASPX-specific thing?  Assuming it can be ignored, you have a JavaScript function in the global scope, so you can declare it to TypeScript and call it like this:

```
// TODO: Replace `any` with a more precise type.
declare function TestFunc(arg: any): void;
// ...
TestFunc("example");
```

(If your TypeScript file is an ES6 module, you'll need to surround the declaration with `declare global { ... }`.)

Comment: I too was confused by the use of `static` there. I had a [quick look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) and apparently it is a part of ES2015 (which I suppose isn't surprising since TS tries to stick to the ES specs). But, like TS it's used within a class, not outside of classes, so it looks like it's just plain "incorrect" in OPs usage.